# grouped bar chart with 2 y-axes is displayed as stacked bar

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I would like to plot the grouped bar chart for the comparison of three methods. I tried the following code and it is displayed as stacked bar chart.can you please help

```
dice =[0, 3, 5];
no_of_region=[42, 12, 5];
figure;
bar(dice',.2,'grouped','FaceColor',[0 .5 .5],'EdgeColor',[0 .9 .9],'LineWidth',1.5)
ylabel('Dice Similarity index')  
yyaxis right
bar(no_of_region, .2,'grouped','EdgeColor', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
legend('Dice Similarity Index','Number of regions')
legend('Location','northwest')
XTickLabel={'a' ; 'b';'c'};
XTick=[1 2 3]
set(gca, 'XTick',XTick);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', XTickLabel);
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 45);
xlabel('Different Methods', 'Fontsize', 16)
ylabel('Number of Regions', 'Fontsize', 16)
title('Comparison of Algorithms', 'fontsize', 20);
set(gcf,'color','w');
```

OUTPUT I GOT AS:
[image]

Comment: The bars aren't actually stacked, that is when one bar starts where the previous one ends. In your case they are drawn on top of each other, covering the smaller bars totally. I guess you want the bars next to each other, a little offset to the left or right?

Comment: how to set offset?

Comment: hb=bar(no_of_region,.2,'stacked','EdgeColor', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
for ib = 1:numel(hb)
    %XData property is the tick labels/group centers; XOffset is the offset
    %of each distinct group
    xData = hb(ib).XData+hb(ib).XOffset;
    
end didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy solution is to shift the bars left and right by half of their width (or more if you would like space between them). Here is the new code, which is also cleaned a bit stylistically:

```
% parameters
dice = [0, 3, 5];
no_of_region = [42, 12, 5];
X = [1, 2, 3]; % common x values for plot
bar_width = 0.2; % width of bars

% initialize figure
figure;

% left plot
bar(X.' - bar_width/2, dice', bar_width, 'grouped', ...
    'FaceColor', [0 .5 .5], ...
    'EdgeColor', [0 .9 .9], ...
    'LineWidth', 1.5);
ylabel('Dice Similarity index');

% right plot
yyaxis right;
bar(X.' + bar_width/2, no_of_region, bar_width, 'grouped', ...
    'EdgeColor', 'r', ...
    'LineWidth', 2);

% plot formatting
legend({'Dice Similarity Index', 'Number of regions'}, ...
    'Location', 'northwest');
XTickLabel = {'a' ; 'b'; 'c'};
XTick = X;
set(gca, ...
    'XTick', XTick, ...
    'XTickLabel', XTickLabel, ...
    'XTickLabelRotation', 45);
xlabel('Different Methods', 'FontSize', 16);
ylabel('Number of Regions', 'FontSize', 16);
title('Comparison of Algorithms', 'FontSize', 20);
set(gcf, 'color', 'w');
```

Depending on desired behavior, you also might consider replacing `figure;` by `clf;`, which clears the existing figure or opens a new figure window if there is not already one open.